# How to rewrite this function into a pointer in c++?

Tags: c++, function, pointers

```
void swap(int &a, int &b)
{
      int temp = a;
      a = b;
      b = temp;
}
```

In my code all I did was add asteriks before the variables `a`, `b` in both the argument and in the body of the code. My teacher said it was wrong so now I don't get it.

Comment: Additionally you have to modify the caller to pass pointers (i.e. add `&` before variables) and you should remove `&` from the argument declaration of `swap`.

Comment: Please show the non-working code and the error message aka [mcve]. The code you psoted is fine (its just not using pointers)

Comment: Your teacher wanted you to do `void swap(int *a, int *b)` You'll need to make some adaptions in the function code then accordingly.

Comment: I think MikeCAT is right. Based on your description it sounds like you had the function correct. That leaves the call. That said, to be certain we need to see exactly wjhat you tried. C++ is unforgiving of even the smallest oversites.

Comment: Mind you, I'm a jerk so I'd have submitted `void swap(int *a, int *b) { std::swap(*a, *b); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
      int temp = *a;
      *a = *b;
      *b = temp;
}
```

the way you would call your original would be:

```
int one = 1;
int two = 2;
swap(one, two); // references
```

the modified function like

```
swap(&one, &two); // pointers
```